# Why in material and render view, some parts of my model are grey?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

So I'm an gfx artist and I do commissions, but for some reason, today when I imported my model file (obj), some parts of it appear grey.
It's not my computer problem, I tried on my other laptop and still, some parts of it are grey. I tried blender 2.90, 2.91, 2.92, and 2.93, but all are the same!
Here are some screenshots

Material view:
[image]
Rendered view:
[image]

Comment: hello please pack your images and share your file (or at least a part of it with grey objects): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: to pack image: File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend. To share your file, upload in  pasteall.org/blend and copy paste here the URL it will give

Comment: it's too big to upload to pasteall- the max is 24mb and my model is 100mb

Comment: you can share one object only. Or use another platform like wetransfer and share the link here

Comment: https://we.tl/t-DRNBtjIDv5

Comment: yes I was able to download it, but actually everything seems ok, if the material looks grey it's because the image textures are grey, is it supposed to be colored?

Comment: Yes it is. I downloaded models from roblox studio, different ones to see, and they are all still gray. It's definitely not how it's supposed to look.

Comment: So is it possibly something wrong with roblox studio and not blender...?

Comment: see, for example, this chushion appears grey but it is supposed to appear grey, the image it uses IS grey: https://zupimages.net/up/21/24/tgev.jpg

Comment: Hmm thats weird... is the dresser also grey? because I clearly remember in roblox studio the dresser being woody brown... if it is grey than I guess it's something wrong with roblox studio

Comment: I see exactly what you show in your pictures, so yes there must be a problem somewhere, I hope someone will understand